# MYSQL query with year and month

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I can't find why `DATE(created) LIKE '2016-1%'` does not return from database anything, while `DATE(created) LIKE '2016%'` will return the row with date 2016-1-22, this column is timestamp format with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE DATE(created) LIKE '2016-1%'
```

I can't find the row either with 2016-1-22 ...

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE` part of a `TIMESTAMP` column is retrieved by MySQL in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` ([see documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)). So a date like 2016-1-22 is actually represented as `2016-01-22`, which does not match `'2016-1%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing month filed with 0, till 9(i.e. 01,02,03,..).
So your query should become like

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE DATE(created) LIKE '2016-01%'
```